# Display the Next Permutation

Tags: c++

I am given an array of integers for which I have to find the next lexicographically greater permutation of its integer.

I am trying to execute the following code

```
class Solution {
public:
    void nextPermutation(vector<int>& nums) {

        int n = nums.size() , i , l;
        for(int i = n-2 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            if(nums[i] < nums[i+1])
            break;
        }
        if(i<0) {
            reverse(nums.begin() , nums.end());
        }
        else{
            for(int l = n-1 ; l > i ; l--){
                if(nums[l]>nums[i])
                break;
            }
            swap(nums[i], nums[l]);
            reverse(nums.begin() + i + 1 , nums.end());
        }
        }
    };
```

Here the problem I am facing is, the following test case shows an error:

```
nums = [3,2,1]

Output received : [3,1,2]

Expected Output : [1,2,3]
```

I am not able to figure out where my code goes wrong.
Also , if in the following code snippet, from the for loop if I remove 'int' then no test cases are getting passed.

```
else{
            for(l = n-1 ; l > i ; l--){
                if(nums[l]>nums[i])
                break;
            }
            swap(nums[i], nums[l]);
            reverse(nums.begin() + i + 1 , nums.end());
        }
```

I am getting the following output:

```
nums =
[1,2,3]
Output
[3,1,2]
Expected
[1,3,2]


nums =
[1,1,5]
Output
[5,1,1]
Expected
[1,5,1]
```

Comment: Why do you have all of this code instead of a simple two-line function: `void nextPermutation(vector<int>& nums) { std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); std::next_permutation(nums.begin(), nums.end()); }`.  The usage of that `Solution` class suggests this question comes from one of those "competitive competition" websites.  If so, isn't the goal to "beat the competition"?  If so, writing *less* code should be the winner. [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: You haven't defined what "next" is.    In any event, the C++ standard library (in standard header `<algorithm>`) has `std::next_permutation()` which satisfies "one" definition of "next".   All you need to do is `std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end())` then a loop to call `std::next_permutation(nums.begin(), nums.end())` until it returns `false`.

Comment: @JaMiT 'The next permutation of an array of integers is the next lexicographically greater permutation of its integer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 minor problems in your code, which leads to wrong output.

At the top, you define some variables in scope of the complete function:

`int n = nums.size(), i, l;`

Please note: You should always initialize all variables. You compiler will emit a warning and tell you. But this is not the reason for the bug.

In both of the `for` loops, you define new variables 'i'  and 'l' which will hide the same variables in function scope. They are now different variables. And they vanish, together with their values after the for loops.

Simply use you variables that you defined on function scope and it will work.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {
public:
    void nextPermutation(std::vector<int>& nums) {

        int n = nums.size(), i, l;
        for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {  // New definition of variable i hides outer definition of i
            if (nums[i] < nums[i + 1])
                break;
        }
        if (i < 0) {
            std::reverse(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        }
        else {
            for (l = n - 1; l > i; l--) { // New definition of variable l hides outer definition of l
                if (nums[l] > nums[i])
                    break;
            }
            std::swap(nums[i], nums[l]);
            std::reverse(nums.begin() + i + 1, nums.end());
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    auto print = [](const std::vector<int>& v) { for (int i : v)std::cout << i << ' '; std::cout << '\n'; };
    std::vector v{ 3,2,1 };
    Solution solution;

    for (int k = 0; k < 10;++k) {
        solution.nextPermutation(v);
        print(v);
    }
}
```